# How do I make text dissolve into particles, then have those particles turn into another text?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, mesh, particles, physics

I have this working up until the 3rd text, I'm using keyed physics to do it, and so far I've been following [this tutorial from tutor4u](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=do0jF3zb5_U)

I have it working just like the video, but once it gets to the transition into the third text, instead of the 2nd text turning into particles and transforming into the 3rd text; the particles appear out of the 2nd text but the text remains.

The 3rd text then forms but the 2nd text will not go away, so they end up overlapping.

I plan to set this up with 4 texts for a YouTube outro.

Here is the order: (Thanks for Watching --> Like --> Comment --> Subscribe)

Thank you to anyone who could point me in the right direction, your input is much appreciated!

Here is the blend file, i have only added the first three texts for now.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0qkz8mj6svjkdpb/Outro.blend?dl=0

Comment: Could you post your blend file. It's impossible to diagnose with this little info.

Comment: Darn, I knew I was missing something. Unfortunately, I'm posting this from my phone right now as I do not have access to my computer at the moment. Tomorrow I will post the blend file.

Comment: just added the blend file, sorry it took so long.